# Select all values of a variables for which there is data for every year

Tags: r, date, time-series, as.date

Say I have some data with 2 numeric variables ranging from 0 to 1 (it1, it2), a name variable, which has the name of the subject the numeric variable belongs to and then some date for every measure, ranging from year 2014 to 2017. Now, what I want to do is create a data set that only contains measures of people that have values for every year of my measure, and then in the future maybe specify that I only want measures for people with data ranging from 2015 to 2017. Does anybody have any hint on what package or code could help me with my problem? Thanks in advance.

```
date <- c("2015-11-26", "2015-12-30","2016-11-13", "2014-09-22", "2014-01-13", "2014-07-26", "2016-11-26", "2016-04-04", "2017-04-09", "2017-02-23", "2015-03-22")
names <- c("Max", "Allen", "Allen", "Bob", "Max", "Sarah", "Max", "Sarah", "Max", "Sarah", "Sarah")
it1 <- c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7)
it2 <- c(0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4)

date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

myframe <- data.frame(date, names, it1, it2)
```

## Desired output:

```
date <- c("2015-11-26", "2014-01-13", "2014-07-26", "2016-11-26", "2016-04-04", "2017-04-09", "2017-02-23", "2015-03-22")
names <- c("Max", "Max", "Sarah", "Max", "Sarah", "Max", "Sarah", "Sarah")
it1 <- c(0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.7)
it2 <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4)

date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

myframe <- data.frame(date, names, it1, it2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table of year vs. name and for those names in all years select out those rows.  No packages are used.

```
tab <- table(as.POSIXlt(myframe$date)$year + 1900, myframe$names)
subset(myframe, names %in% colnames(tab)[colSums(sign(tab)) == nrow(tab)])
```

giving:

```
         date names it1 it2
1  2015-11-26   Max 0.6 0.5
5  2014-01-13   Max 0.3 0.4
6  2014-07-26 Sarah 0.8 0.4
7  2016-11-26   Max 0.8 0.5
8  2016-04-04 Sarah 0.5 0.8
9  2017-04-09   Max 0.5 0.6
10 2017-02-23 Sarah 0.3 0.5
11 2015-03-22 Sarah 0.7 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
myframe[with(data = myframe[year(myframe$date) >= 2014 & year(myframe$date) <= 2017,],
             expr = ave(year(date), names, FUN = function(x)
                 all(year(date) %in% x))) == 1,]
#         date names it1 it2
#1  2015-11-26   Max 0.6 0.5
#5  2014-01-13   Max 0.3 0.4
#6  2014-07-26 Sarah 0.8 0.4
#7  2016-11-26   Max 0.8 0.5
#8  2016-04-04 Sarah 0.5 0.8
#9  2017-04-09   Max 0.5 0.6
#10 2017-02-23 Sarah 0.3 0.5
#11 2015-03-22 Sarah 0.7 0.4
```